# Error with connection with adodb in php

Tags: php, mysql, adodb-php

Hello a trying connect to database and i cant do this , i run the program with laragon and show this errors.
the database connection is with adodb with mysql.
Thanks for help.

```html
Deprecated: Methods with the same name as their class will not be constructors in a future version of PHP; ADODB_Cache_File has a deprecated constructor in C:\laragon\www\FacturaElectronicaAlumgo\sistema\adodb5\adodb.inc.php on line 233

Deprecated: Methods with the same name as their class will not be constructors in a future version of PHP; ADOConnection has a deprecated constructor in C:\laragon\www\FacturaElectronicaAlumgo\sistema\adodb5\adodb.inc.php on line 327

Deprecated: Methods with the same name as their class will not be constructors in a future version of PHP; ADORecordSet has a deprecated constructor in C:\laragon\www\FacturaElectronicaAlumgo\sistema\adodb5\adodb.inc.php on line 2854

Deprecated: Methods with the same name as their class will not be constructors in a future version of PHP; ADORecordSet_array has a deprecated constructor in C:\laragon\www\FacturaElectronicaAlumgo\sistema\adodb5\adodb.inc.php on line 3872

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_pconnect() in C:\laragon\www\FacturaElectronicaAlumgo\sistema\adodb5\drivers\adodb-mysql.inc.php:383 Stack trace: #0 C:\laragon\www\FacturaElectronicaAlumgo\sistema\adodb5\adodb.inc.php(588): ADODB_mysql->_pconnect('localhost', 'root', 'black44265769', 'cal24412_dte') #1 C:\laragon\www\FacturaElectronicaAlumgo\sistema\conexion.php(3): ADOConnection->PConnect('localhost', 'root', 'black44265769', 'cal24412_dte') #2 C:\laragon\www\FacturaElectronicaAlumgo\sistema\validar.php(8): include('C:\\laragon\\www\\...') #3 {main} thrown in C:\laragon\www\FacturaElectronicaAlumgo\sistema\adodb5\drivers\adodb-mysql.inc.php on line 383
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What PHP version? I'm assuming 7.x here (possibly) due to the 'deprecated' messages and the last 'fatal' error.

It's a two part matter...

1. The deprecated:

   PHP has made a change to use `__construct()`
   (two leading underscores) as the constructor instead of having the same name as the class itself. See the [PHP 4 style constructors](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.deprecated.php) section (first section on the page) for more information.

   For example: In the file to `ADOConnection has a deprecated
   constructor...` the constructor likely looks like this:

   ```
   ADOConnection( ... ); // constructors with or without parameters
   ```

   ...but all of those can be replaced with:

   ```
   __construct( ... );
   ```

   You can make that change locally to resolve the deprecated messages.
2. The fatal error:

   With PHP 7.x, the mysql_* based functions are
   removed. See [this API info](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-pconnect.php).

Comment: thanks for the answer , y solve the dreprecate error , now i try to solve the fatal error with you same api info  your answer helped me a lot , really very thanks PD: 
I am not used to working with PHP and the system I had in the company with many errors so it is a bit difficult for me, and thanks again

Comment: To solve that other, you will not be able to use the `mysql_*`. You will need to use either `mysqli_*` (note the trailing **i**) or PDO handling.

Comment: You did not specify which version of ADOdb you're running. The PHP 4 constructors were removed in version 5.20.2, I suggest you upgrade your library code to the latest version.

Comment: With regards to the undefined mysql function error, make sure that your code uses the 'mysqli' driver initializing your database object (look for a NewADOConnection or ADONewConnection function call)